# Changing one particle in the particle system affects all

Tags: objects, particles, linked-data, instances

I made a large structure with small spheres using the particle system function. Changing the source object changes everything, which is expected. But Now I want to just change one of the spheres to be red and also change the shape to something else like polyhedral.
So I used the "make instances real" function. This gives me individual spheres to work with. I can move/delete etc. But I can't change the color of the individual spheres. I made another shape and gave it the color red. But when I am trying to assign the new red object to one of the spheres it affects all and all becomes red.

Seems like all the spheres are linked together.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give your object a different material, but keep the mesh linked, in the *Material* panel, click on the *Link* button and choose *Object*, it will unlink the materials. If you want to do it for several objects, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> when you press on *Object* :

[image]

To unlink the mesh of a single object, go into the *Object Data* panel and press on the *Make Single User* button:

[image]

If you want to unlink several objects, select them all and go into *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*. If you want to unlink the materials as well, choose *Object & Data & Materials*:

[image]